# What is the best way to get a broadcast address from an ip address?

Tags: android, wifi, broadcast

I'm writing an android application which should send out broadcast packets over WiFi.

Currently I can get the IP address of the device from `WifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getIpAddress()` and guess the broadcast address by simply replacing the last digit with 0. But I really don't like this solution.

What would be the proper way?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to replace with `255` not with `0`.

If you are targeting SDK 9 or later you can use `getBroadcast()`, otherwise you need to overide the numbers in IP address.

Example code:

```
public static InetAddress getNetworkLocalBroadcastAddressdAsInetAddress() throws IOException {
    for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
        NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
        if(VERSION.SDK_INT < 9) { 
            if(!intf.getInetAddresses().nextElement().isLoopbackAddress()){
                byte[] quads = intf.getInetAddresses().nextElement().getAddress();
                quads[0] = (byte)255;
                quads[1] = (byte)255;
                return InetAddress.getByAddress(quads);
            }
        }else{
            if(!intf.isLoopback()){
                List<InterfaceAddress> intfaddrs = intf.getInterfaceAddresses();
                return intfaddrs.get(0).getBroadcast(); //return first IP address
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: It is not possible to know the broadcast address without knowing the subnet mask.  Your implementation naively assumes a specific subnet size.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
    public static String getBroadcast(){
    String found_bcast_address=null;
     System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv4Stack", "true"); 
        try
        {
          Enumeration<NetworkInterface> niEnum = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
          while (niEnum.hasMoreElements())
          {
            NetworkInterface ni = niEnum.nextElement();
            if(!ni.isLoopback()){
                for (InterfaceAddress interfaceAddress : ni.getInterfaceAddresses())
                {

                  found_bcast_address = interfaceAddress.getBroadcast().toString();
                  found_bcast_address = found_bcast_address.substring(1);

                }
            }
          }
        }
        catch (SocketException e)
        {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return found_bcast_address;
}
```